# Javascript validation breaks when submitting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been working on a simple form that will have several (2-3) sets of questions that contain radio buttons as answers. Each radio button has a number value. I was able to work in a logic that shows or hides a text box when the user selects a certain radio button.
In the original code I found, the validation checks only one specific question, but I'm wanting to update the validation code in a way that if ANY of the questions have a text box visible, and its empty, the alert pop up should come up.

Here is a JSFiddle page with the code: https://jsfiddle.net/nxenxoo/92myvwc3/25/

At this moment, if on question #1 I click on radio buttons 1-3, and forget to fill in the text box, move onto the second question and hit radio button 10, for example, the validation works great. I get a pop up.

However, lets say I fill in the text box required for question #1 and leave the text box that appears for question #2, then I get a 404 error upon submit.

I was trying to work in a OR statement || below, I was hoping it would work, but unfortunately it does not.

```
function validateForm(){
    
    var x= $("form input[type=text]").val();  
    if ($('.showother' || '.showother2').is(":visible")) {
    if ( x==null || x=="")

{
alert("Please fill in all text boxes");
return false;
```

I am curious to figure out what could be the problem. I know very little of javascript, so I am sorry if this is a very basic queston!

Comment: Please proper format your example code. 2 `if` but no closing brackets?

Comment: I'm getting a 404 for the JsFiddle. Please update the link or embed the code directly in the post.

Answer (score 0):

HTML

```
<div id="Other" class="showother" style="display:none">Please specify <input name="textbox" id="textbox" type="text">
</div>
...
<div id="Other2" class="showother2" style="display:none">Please specify <input name="textbox" id="textbox2" type="text">
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var x= $("form input[type=text]").val();
...
```

`"form input[type=text]"` matches both text inputs, but only returns the value of the first match.

```
function validateForm(){
    
    var x1= $("#textbox").val(); // first textbox, use id
    var x2= $("#textbox2").val(); // second textbox, use id
    if ($('.showother' || '.showother2').is(":visible")) {

    // check if either are null or empty
    if ( x1==null || x1=="" || x2==null || x2=="") { 
    
      alert("Please fill in all text boxes");
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, check all visible text inputs with one block of code:

```
$("form input[type=text]").each(function() {
  if ( 
    ($(this).parent().is(":visible")) 
    && ($(this).val()==null || $(this).val()=="") 
  ) {
    alert("Please fill in all text boxes");
    return false;
  }
})
```

Comment: Thank you! I am sorry for late reply, I thought I would get alert in mailbox. I just updated it in the jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nxenxoo/0k63wrdg/17/

I am curious to know how I can update the code, if question #3 is not a textbox but a textarea. In the JSFiddle above I replaced the 3rd textbox with a <textarea> that has the same ID, name, type, however it looks like the validation ignores it. Is a "type" of textarea something I can add into the javascript? I've looked online and I'm seeing a completely different approach to this solution. I have a lot to learn.

Comment: Sorry - the correct JSFiddle link: https://jsfiddle.net/nxenxoo/0k63wrdg/24/
, where I updated the form to have a textarea instead of a text field on question 3. Is there a way to add something similar to $("form input[type=text]"), where I tell the javascript code to also take into consideration textareas as well? Or will that have to be a different code?